# Spy function in mock file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a mock file called `StateService` located in a `__mocks__` folder

```js
export default {
    goTo: jest.fn(),
    goToNewTab: jest.fn(),
    goToPreviousAppState: jest.fn(),
    reload: jest.fn()
}
```

In my test, I want to spy `goToNewTab` and check that the function has been called.
What I'm doing right now is importing the mock file into my test and then, in my test itself, I'm calling expect like this:

```js
expect(StateService.goToNewTab).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But the expect is not returning a positive value.

Comment: If you have created the mock inside the `__mocks__` folder, you don't need to import it, jest will do that for you (unless you tell it otherwise). The logic you are following seems right to me, can you please add a minimal version of the relevant code?

Comment: The problem is that I need in my test file to import the StateService from somewhere right? And that's the issue, if I import the mock file, the call count is 0, otherwise I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a file in `services/StateService.js` (for simplicity I will only define the `goToNewTab` service):

```
function goToNewTab() {
    // Your logic here.
}

export default {
    goToNewTab
};
```

Then, you create a mock of this module in `services/__mocks__/StateService.js`:

```
export default {
    goToNewTab: jest.fn()
};
```

Now, you are testing a module that calls the `goToNewTab` service. Let's suppose it is placed in `utils/navigation.js`:

```
import StateService from '../services/StateService';

export default function() {
    StateService.goToNewTab();
}
```

The test for such a module making use of the mocked service would look like:

```
import StateService from '../services/StateService';
import navigation from './navigation';

jest.mock('../services/StateService');

it('Should mock call', () => {
    navigation();

    expect(StateService.goToNewTab).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Note that if you are requiring the `StateService` module in your test, you need to explicitly call `jest.mock` of the module, as stated in the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules).